# CloseComment: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: ()

Tags: apex, trigger, community, before-trigger, triggercontext

I am facing the below issue. Could anyone please help. I have written a trigger on the Case Object. **I am calling this trigger at the time of creating web to case from the HTML Generator code.**

```
Error: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Apex trigger CloseComment caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: CloseComment: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: ()
```

[image]

**I think its nothing do to with trigger. Somewhere Salesforce causing the problem. On my case object There are no triggers active.**

Comment: Can you provide the code to the trigger in question?

Comment: This is only happening on a beforeInsert trigger where you're inserting a case with a status of "closed" from a Customer Community? Does the same trigger work when inserting the case where there's regular Salesforce User creating & closing the case from inside your org?

Comment: You're saying even with the trigger turned off you're seeing an error from that Apex trigger?

Comment: Please check the updates. As I said, its nothing to do with my trigger. All trigger on the Case object are InActive.

Comment: The stack trace and error message clearly indicate that the **`CloseComment`** trigger is the issue here. Please include the code for that trigger, regardless of your assessment of its relevance. Also, does this post actually have anything to do with communities?